# How to fix overlapping faces?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

I was trying to create my model and used primarily beveling/inset. I inset the face and this happened. How do I fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvzjD.png

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126112/discussion-on-question-by-levitatinghorse-how-to-fix-overlapping-faces).

Comment: The tip that caused the discussion was also moved to chat, so here it goes again: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the front faces and and start again.

Make sure to start with just one face.

Select it in Edit Mode. Use Inset Faces and then Extrude Region. No need to Bevel yet unless you want to round off the edges afterwards.